# Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, anonymous-function

I have a general question: in the C# code below thread `tFour` can not be created and the compiler shows me the following error: "*Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value*"

**THE CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DelegatesAndLambda
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int ThrowNum(object a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            return 2 * (int)a;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<int> newF = delegate () { int x = ThrowNum(2); return x; };
            Thread tOne = new Thread( delegate () { int x = ThrowNum(2); });
            Thread tTwo= new Thread(()=> ThrowNum(2));
            Thread tThree = new Thread(() => newF());
            Thread tFour = new Thread(delegate () { int x = ThrowNum(2); return x;});
        }
    }
}
```

However, threads `tOne`, `tTwo` and `tThree` are created without an error. So why does the lambda expression allows to pass a method delegate with return (non-void) value and multiple parameters (`ThrowNum(2), newF()`) while an anonymous method with return value ( `delegate () { int x = ThrowNum(2); return x;}`)  defined using the delegate keyword can not be passed? I thought in both cases we deal with anonymous methods?  I do know that `Thread`  accepts only two types of signatures : `void DoSomething()` and void `DoSomething(object o)`  but what is the major difference between initializations of `tTwo` and `tFour` using the same(?) anonymous method? I have been trying to find answer for a while but did not succeed.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just because an expression-bodied lambda expression has a result doesn't mean it's used. It's fine for a lambda expression that returns a result to be converted to a delegate with a `void` return type, so long as its body is a valid *statement expression*. Here's a simple example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static int Method() => 5;

    static void Main()
    {
        Action action = () => Method();
    }
}
```

That's fine, because `Method()` is be a valid statement expression. It just calls the method, and ignores the result. This would *not* be valid, because `1 + 1` isn't a valid statement expression:

```
// error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement,
//               await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
Action action = () => 1 + 2;
```

There's no such thing as an expression-bodied anonymous method, so thing become a bit simpler: you just can't return a value from an anonymous method and convert that anonymous method to a delegate type with a `void` return type.

The relevant part of the C# 5 ECMA standard is 11.7.1:

> Specifically, an anonymous function F is compatible with a delegate type D provided:
>
> - ...
> - If the body of F is an expression, and either D has a void return type or F is async and D has the return
>     type Task, then when each parameter of F is given the type of the corresponding parameter in D, the
>     body of F is a valid expression (w.r.t §12) that would be permitted as a statement-expression (§13.7).

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks for the response.
Where can I read about C# 5 ECMA standard? Specifically about  anonymous functions and their delegates?

Comment: Well you can get the standard for free, and read as much of it as you want :) https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm